# How to force identical Excel "pixel" sizes at different screen resolutions and scalings on Windows 10?

Tags: excel, vba, windows

Excel is adjusting column width and row height depending on the screen resolution and scaling settings in Windows 10. The Excel tool I am working on needs to produce printable Excel sheets, that can be viewed on different machines keeping the correct cell dimensions and thus formatting.

The goal is that the sheets are displayed correctly **independently of the Windows screen resolution or scaling**!

I am aware of the so-called "pixels" in Excel and their dependence on these Windows settings. However, as there are no fractions of pixels, this leads to (slightly) different cell sizes on different screens. What I would like to do, is to adjust the pixel size in the Excel sheet.

However, I am not sure that this is possible, plus maybe there is a simpler solution I cannot see. VBA seems to provide tools only for the readout of the ratio of pixel to points, e.g., [PointsToScreenPixelsY](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.window.pointstoscreenpixelsy) but no possibility to adjust the ratio.

**Example:**

> This example determines the height and width (in pixels) of the
> selected cells in the active window and returns the values in the
> lWinWidth and lWinHeight variables.

```vba
With ActiveWindow 
 lWinWidth = _ 
 .PointsToScreenPixelsX(.Selection.Width) 
 lWinHeight = _ 
 .PointsToScr
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue, but maybe [PageSetup.FitToPagesTall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.fittopagestall) and [PageSetup.FitToPagesWide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.fittopageswide) may be helpful?

Comment: If you're talking about the display of the worksheet to the user, maybe you're looking for [Window.VisibleRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.visiblerange). Monitoring that property would allow you to zoom or resize rows & columns until the user is seeing the correct number of rows & columns.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try that out and give an update on whether it worked out